# Conflicting notation of the term random variable

Tags: probability, notation, random-variables

I'm kind of confused how the notation of a random variable $X$ is used. As I understand it, a random variable $X$ is a function

$$X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$$

which maps every possible outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ to a unique value in set, with which we can work with better mathematically (which is usually $\mathbb{R}$). So far so good.

Now for probabilites the usual way of writing them is "$P(X)$". But what should that mean? "The probability of a function" doesn't make sense to me. Does it actually mean "$P(X(\Omega))$"? Then what do $P(X = x)$ or $P(X \le x)$ mean?

I came across this while trying to understand the definitions of the different probability distributions. Every definition I can find seems to have this weird notation usage. Can somebody explain to me in a really clear way how the notation is used here?

Comment: Provide some examples please. I know of some uses of $P(X)$ to mean $\int X dP$ but it would be best if you provided the specific instance you wanted help with.

Comment: The notation $P(X)$ doesn’t make sense (unless the author is adopting their idiosyncratic definition for this).  For others, they are just abbreviations for the probability $P(\{\omega:X(\omega)=x\})$ and $P(\{\omega:X(\omega)\leq x\})$. So they are probabilities of some events (i.e. measurable subsets of $\Omega$) which is realized as inverse images of some sets under $X$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I guess this notation is the typical notation, since it's used almost everywhere I searched: Wikipedia, PDFs, even on https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/random-variables.html
I mean I'd be happy if you can give me a counterexample.

Comment: the notation $P(X)$ I offered earlier is used in the context of using the duality between continuous bounded functions and radon measures. None of those pages as far as I am aware use exactly $P(X)$. Its always $P(X\dots)$ where the $\dots$ are very very important stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the definition of random variable right.  But I always found it confusing to think of a random variable as a measurable function. Instead, it's a variable that you don't know the value of for sure, but only that you know the *probablity* of it taking certain values (or having a value in a certain interval).

But to be strict, when the probabilists write $P(X=x)$, they mean $P(X^{-1}(x))$, and $P(X\leq x)$ means $P(X^{-1}(-\infty,x])$.